# Django avatar class not work

Tags: python, css, django, avatar

In django-avatar I want to add a custom CSS class using the template tag, but it's not working.

My template:

```
{% load avatar_tags %}

<li>
     <span class="userhome">
     {% avatar user 50 class="mmb-img" id="user_avatar" %} 
     Welcome : {{ user.username }}
     </span>
</li>
```

The rendered HTML is:

```
<li>
    <span class="userhome">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4bbcb352e5bdbe63fe8f9a5786ea9d69/?s=50" alt="cpoudevigne" width="50" height="50"> 
    Welcome : cpoudevigne
    </span>
</li>
```

The custom class does not appear. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue here, unable to set neither class="" nor id="".

No idea what's going on, so temporarily I can only set it via JavaScript/JQuery.

JQuery:

```
$(function() {$("span.userhome img").addClass("img-responsive")});
```

Comment: I try your solution and this class is not add 
My script.js :
`$(document).ready(function() {

    $("span .userhome").addClass("mmb-img")});
    
});`

Comment: i try this and work ^^ :
`$(function() {$("span.userhome img").addClass("<my-class>")});` Thanks Valorad

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because the app [caches the output of those template tags](http://django-avatar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#global-settings):

> `AVATAR_CACHE_ENABLED`
>
> Set to `False` if you completely disable avatar caching. Defaults to `True`.

Either change the `AVATAR_CACHE_ENABLED` setting or clear your cache.

Comment: I write CACHE_ENABLED in my settings.py, set up to False and not work. I'm going to lib/python2.7/site-packages/avatar/conf.py for see the configuration.

Comment: The setting is `AVATAR_CACHE_ENABLED`, not `CACHE_ENABLED`. Have you tried the first one?

Comment: Yes i try AVATAR_CACHE_ENABLED and this not working and im going see the configuration in site-packages/avatar and i see CACHE_ENABLED.

Comment: up ? :p you have idea ?

Comment: No, sorry. There must be something else going on that we cannot see from the code you have posted.

Comment: im searching, if i have the solution, i post here ^^ thanks :).